# Add new index for map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am attempting to create a Recipe project in Groovy, at the moment i've got a simple recipe class that holds the recipe ID and recipe name, I then have a RecipeBook class which creates a new map and then a method called addRecipe to add recipes to the map. At the moment my recipes just overwrite eachother in the map rather than add one after the other.

```
   class Recipe {

        int id
        String name
        def ingredients

    }

class RecipeBook {

    // Create a map to store our recipes
    def recipeList = [:]

    // Use closure to add recipes to the map
    def addRecipe =  { id,name ->
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(id: id, name: name)
        recipeList.put('id',recipe.id)
        recipeList.put('name',recipe.name)
        // Last element gets returned
        recipeList
    }


}
RecipeBook recipe = new RecipeBook()

recipe.addRecipe(1, "Chicken Soup")

recipe.addRecipe(2, "Lemon Chicken")

println recipe.recipeList
```

After adding the 2 recipes my array just holds 2 : Lemon Chicken

Comment: Why did you include `ruby` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add your `recipe`s to the `recipeList`, but on each `addRecipe` call you set `recipeList.id` and `recipelist.name`. I guess instead of

```
recipeList.put('id',recipe.id)
recipeList.put('name',recipe.name)
```

you want something like

```
recipeList.put id, recipe
```

Comment: More likely the OP will want `recipeList.put(id, recipe)`.